# How to disable arrows UP and DOWN in JFormattedTextField with date formatter factory

Tags: java, keypress, jformattedtextfield

I have written this code:

```
JFormattedTextField formatedField= new JFormattedTextField();
formatedField.setFormatterFactory (new DefaultFormatterFactory (new Date Formatter (new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"))));
```

After you type the date in the field and the cursor when you press the up arrow date changes. But I have written code that when you press the up arrow moves the cursor to another field. Therefore, when changing the cursor changes to data. Does anyone know how to disable changing the date in this field by the arrow?

Exactly what I'm talking:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SByNt.gif)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the more common way to move from one form field to the next is by using the Tab (forward) and the Shift-Tab (backward).  The user experience (UX) should not change from one Java application to another.

Comment: Sure, and you're right. But in the previous application has just so it worked. So you can not change the habits of the user!